# Generate a repeating index for length of list

Tags: python

I know I can do the follow :

```
files = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

for ind, file in enumerate(files):
    print(ind, file)

(0, 'a')
(1, 'b')
(2, 'c')
(3, 'd')
(4, 'e')
(5, 'f')
```

I'd like to generate a second index that repeats between 0 and `n-1` over the length of the list.  For example, if `n=2` `print(ind, file, ind2)` yields

```
(0, 'a', 0)
(1, 'b', 1)
(2, 'c', 0)
(3, 'd', 1)
(4, 'e', 0)
(5, 'f', 1)
```

and if `n=3`

```
(0, 'a', 0)
(1, 'b', 1)
(2, 'c', 2)
(3, 'd', 0)
(4, 'e', 1)
(5, 'f', 2)
```

Comment: errr `print(ind, file, ind % 3)`

Comment: ugh ... duh.  Yes that's exactly what I want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is trivial with modulus operator:

```
for ind, file in enumerate(files):
    print(ind, file, ind % 3)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of `itertools.cycle` and `zip`.

```
from itertools import cycle
files = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
n = 3
print(list(zip(range(len(files)), files, cycle(range(n)))))
```

This outputs:

```
[(0, 'a', 0), (1, 'b', 1), (2, 'c', 2), (3, 'd', 0), (4, 'e', 1), (5, 'f', 2)]
```

Comment: Definitely overkill here… but also definitely worth learning about for the future when the OP has a less trivial question.